# Google Script, find match value from one column with another column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am try to make "Color check",
It will change color when value input is detected.

I need to find match value from one column with another column.
Find match for each value in each value in the column.

But my code dont work, can anyone help with my code?

Here is my code:

```js
function checkScriptCheck() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var datePaymentValues = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var dateInputValues = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var datePaymentRange = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  
  var datePaymentColumn = sheet.getRange("A:A").getColumn();
  var checkResultValueColumn =sheet.getRange("C:C").getColumn()
  
  //cleaning color
  datePaymentRange.setBackground("white");
  
  //check and coloring
  for(i=0;i<datePaymentValues.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<dateInputValues.length;j++){
      if(datePaymentValues[i][0]==dateInputValues[j][0]){
        sheet.getRange(i+1, datePaymentColumn).setBackground("green");
        sheet.getRange(i+1, checkResultValueColumn).setValue("check");
      };
    };
  };
  
};
```

Here is the link to my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DVbNaehsTWkiIkzW2nQx7w-ZB8CrPmSP5T5CpU24mbU/edit?usp=sharing

Here is some screenshoot:

[Sheet Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwsVR.png)

[Code ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJKsD.png)

Thankyou.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Please edit your question with the appropriate necessary details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be easier if you create a map of values to check for first.

```
function checkScriptCheck() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var datePaymentRange = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var datePaymentValues = datePaymentRange.getValues();
  var dateInputValues = sheet.getRange("B:B").getValues();

  var datePaymentColumn = datePaymentRange.getColumn();
  var checkResultValueColumn =sheet.getRange("C:C").getColumn()

  //cleaning color
  datePaymentRange.setBackground("white");

  //create map of values to check for
  var inputDates = {};
  for (var i = 1; i < dateInputValues.length; i++) { // Exclude header row
    var inputDate = dateInputValues[i][0];
    if (inputDate != "") { // Exclude blank values
      inputDates[inputDate] = true;
    }    
  }

  //check and coloring
  for (var i = 1; i < datePaymentValues.length; i++) { // Exclude header row
    var paymentDate = datePaymentValues[i][0];
    if (inputDates[paymentDate]) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, datePaymentColumn).setBackground("#00ff00");
      sheet.getRange(i+1, checkResultValueColumn).setValue("check");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Diego, thanks for the help!
your Code is working!

Sorry about my bad question, i dont know how to question because i dont really understand how to describe it